Power filtering -- why, and how do I "see" it? (simulation program? Something?)
I know little about electrical engineering, I am just starting out.
I have a question about power filtering.
It all started when I noticed that this product has it:
https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1493.html
It had three capacitors to perform some power filtering.
When I asked why, I was told that since this sensor is powered by a 5-12V wide voltage supply, they parallel several small capacitors between VCC and GND for power filtering.
So… questions:

What is power filtering exactly?

Why is it needed with wider voltage ranges?

How do the capacitors in parallel “filter” things?

(MOST IMPORTANT) Is there a way to simulate circuits online, and go as far as (a) Providing unfiltered “messy” voltage (b) "See the provided voltage in real time (c) Apply the small capacitors (d) See in real time how the voltage is filtered?


Thank you.


Filtering means removing high frequencies like AC noise and leaving only stable DC that doesn't fluctuate.

It isn't needed with wide voltage ranges. It's needed always, and even more important when voltage range is small. With 3.3V or 0.9V supply voltage for sensitive ICs, even +/- 0.05 V ripple is too much and intended signals are swamped with noise.

Capacitors store energy, and they try to keep the voltage that's 'stored' over them, and they resist the voltage change by charging and discharging current. They are like small local batteries that can provide a burst of current to a nearby load, instead of voltage dropping over wires if there is a longer wiring to actual supply.

Sure, there are many simulators, as programs or web pages. Even this website integrates one, even though it is mainly used for drawing schematics to questions and answers. Spice based simulators are generally freely available from many vendors, and Falstad is often referred here as simulator website.



Is it always good to have such a filter in my power supply? And is it always good to have such a filter in the power provided to my sensors? When do I use them?

@Merc that is a bit arbitrary question so you get a bit arbitrary answer. Bypass caps are usually used to keep things working regardless of what powers them. Especially when you buy some modules, you can never know how someone tries to use those modules, so the modules have bypass caps, because otherwise it might work for some users and not for other users. You basically look at data sheet examples and put a capacitor where the data sheet tells you.
